# React login form values comparison with default config values

Tags: reactjs, validation, authentication, react-component

I'm working with reactJS login form. I would like to have input value for email and password in the config file. For example, email should be: xxx@gmail.com and password should be: password. 
I able to set the this.state.email and this.state.passsword value, but I can't able to figure out how to compare those values with default values in the config file. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import Header from '../../components/header';
import '../../assets/css/style.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router'



function validate(email, password) {
    return {
        email: email.length === 0,
        password: password.length === 0,
    };
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            everFocusedEmail: false,
            everFocusedPassword: false,
        };
    }

handleEmailChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ email: evt.target.value });
}

handlePasswordChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ password: evt.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}

canBeSubmitted() {
    const errors = validate(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
    return !isDisabled;
}

render() {
    const errors = validate(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 vertical-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <div className="card loginFormDiv">
                            <h3>Login</h3>
                            <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="loginForm">
                                    <div className="input-group formInputDiv">
                                      <span className="input-group-addon">
                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                      </span>
                                        <input type="text" className={`form-control loginForm ${errors.email ? "error" : ""}`} value={this.state.email}
                                               onChange={this.handleEmailChange} placeholder="Enter your email"></input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="input-group formInputDiv">
                                      <span className="input-group-addon">
                                          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
                                      </span>
                                        <input type="password" className={`form-control loginForm  ${errors.password ? "error" : ""}`}
                                               onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} placeholder="Enter your password"></input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="text-right">
                                        <Link to={'/dashboard'}><button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary loginBtn" disabled={isDisabled}>Log In</button></Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
    export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing initial values. You can write your constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        password: 'password',
        everFocusedEmail: false,
        everFocusedPassword: false,
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please me the better way to store email and password in the config file and import functions?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your config file is a json file. And it has the following information in it.

```
//config.js
{
  "user" : {
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "password": "1234pass"
  }
}
```

Now in your react component you can import this config file, and use it's user.email and user.password as default and check it against the user input value.

```
//LoginForm.js
import React from "react";
import Header from '../../components/header';
import '../../assets/css/style.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

//importing config file
import config from './config.js'; //whatever is the correct path


function validate(email, password) {
    return {
        email: email.length === 0,
        password: password.length === 0,
    };
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            everFocusedEmail: false,
            everFocusedPassword: false,
        };
    }

handleEmailChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ email: evt.target.value });
    if(this.state.email === config.user.email) {
        /* This is checking user input as user types against default 
        email in the config file.
        */

        //do anything 
    }
}

handlePasswordChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ password: evt.target.value });
    if(this.state.password === config.user.password) {
        /* This is checking user input as user types against default 
        password in the config file.
        */

        //do anything 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.